# How to link to original dir by linking a link to that dir?

Tags: shell, directory, symlink

Here is the sample

```
$ mkdir original_dir
$ ln -s original_dir link
$ ls -l
original_dir
link -> original_dir
```

Now I want to create a new link to `original_dir` by linking to `link`, how can I do that

```
$ ln [--link-to-original-file] link newLink
```

Or any other commands that do the same thing?

Comment: `ln -s "$(readlink -f link)" newlink`, but most of the time `ln -s link newlink` would work exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a **symbolic link** by using `readlink` as suggested by @SatoKatsura:

```
ln -s "$(readlink -f link)" newLink
```

If you create a simple symbolic link via `ln -s link newLink`, `newLink` would point to `link`, which itself points to `original_dir`.